# I'm having trouble hooking up a new printer. It says it is not communicating

Tags: drivers, printer

[image: Error Pop-Up]

That is the error I am getting. This printer worked fine previously for a short time, however now whenever I attempt to print from a web page the error box displays.  I have printed a test page from the printers menu, and that works fine.  I have already attempted to resolve the issue multiple times by following the on-screen suggestions, but to no avail.  Can anyone help me resolve my issue?  This is a serious problem with my productivity as my printer is an essential part of working.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't sure where to place it.  I'll move it immediately.

Comment: belongs on another site, but I cannot select one that makes sense in the dialog